# C3 JS Change X Axis, ticking values makes the chart disappear

Tags: javascript, graph, axis, c3.js

I am new to Javascript, and I have figured out few things but can't seem to figure out why the X Axis has a hard time changing. I am using the C3 library to make the stacked bar charts. When I manually try to change the tick to an array of Values:

```
axis: {
        x : {
            type : {
                tick: {
                    // values: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
                    multiline:false,
                    culling: {
                        max: 1
                    },
                },
            },
            label : {
                text: 'Days',
                position: 'center-bottom',

            },
```

The graph will not change the ticks on the axis. Line 17 in the Codepen JS line of code that I tried to change the X Axis. Any help would be appreciated.

Link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgNEYm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `tick` declaration shouldn't be nested in the `type` declaration, they should be siblings of each other. C3 won't pick up anything you declare in `tick` because of this.

Secondly, `values` works by matching to values in the data series declared as containing the x axis values, like numbers in a normal chart, or dates in a time-series chart --> http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_values.html . Neither of your series is declared as holding the x axis values, and both are numerical data anyways, so strings like "Monday" etc will never match.

Thirdly, that codepen was using a really out-of-date version of c3 (I had to update it to get the solution below to work), so the c3 code that was running would have been hopelessly out of date to any of the c3 docs online

What you're looking for here I suspect is to use the category type and declare the categories as so:

```
         x : {
           type: 'category',
           categories:  ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
           tick: {
                multiline:false,
                culling: {
                    max: 1
                },
            },
        },
        ... etc etc...
    },
```

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjNKya

Comment: Wow... an eye opener. Thank you so much, I will check up on the c3/d3 libraries I am currently using in my software too! Many thanks :)